# Swagger codegen failed: missing swagger input or config

Tags: python, swagger-codegen

I have [this json file](https://gist.github.com/sagunji/9a7a39c102d5638bfb557314d2237a37#file-api-docs-json) and I have been trying to create models and API code through swagger codegen. This has not been quiet effective as it throws error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:735)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:285)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
```

The swagger docs version is 1.2. And I am using swagger-codegen version 2.4.0.

```
java -jar modules\swagger-codegen-cli\target\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i ./json/docs.json -l python -o C:/Users/sk/projects/generated-sdk
```

Comment: What version of Swagger Codegen are you using? How do you run the Codegen? Which target are you generating?

Comment: @Helen I have udated the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the yaml file, if you do not strictly have the indent, you can get the error like this. For swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar, the error message won't tell you which row is wrong. (Just not sure whether this get fixed in the newer version. )